# How do you get into Vulnerability Research as a career?

Tags: exploit, vulnerability-analysis, development

How do you break into Vulnerability Research (with focus on mobile security).

I noticed that all vulnerability research positions expect you to already have the knowledge and career experience, other than few government-sponsored training programs (which I'm not eligible for).

so I would appreciate getting some advice on how I can pivot my career to that direction.

some background: I started as a SOC analyst, then moved into DFIR, with focus on malware reversing (effecting x86 platforms most of the time, some few occasions ARM/MIPS malware), I wrote tools in C/C++ as well as detection scripts in Python and Lua.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. I'm afraid this question isn't a good fit for our Q&A site. The issue is that it elicits opinions rather than facts. Could you perhaps edit it to be a better fit? The [help center](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help) should help.